Specific section of string comma separated
I have a csv file with some numbers and words. Example,



Header




1 This is the first line.


This is the second line.


3 4 This is the third line.


5 6 7 This is a special line.



Trying to separate these numbers into a separate column. Like this,



number1
number2
number3
Text




1
--------
--------
This is the first line.


--------
--------
-------
This is the second line.


3
4
--------
This is the third line.


5
6
7
This is a special line.



I am trying to solve it via Python RegEx. It will be helpful if anyone kindly guides me with any solution.

You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

The regexp ^([\d\s]+) will match the numbers at the beginning of the line. You can then split the result of this capture group with str.split(). The rest of the line will go in Text.

You have a CSV file that doesn't contain any commas?

What he actually has is a text file.

Why does the title say "comma separated"? There are no comma separators in the file.

I didn't get notified of your reply, you misspelled my name. Do you know that there's automatical name completion, just type "@B" and it will fill out the name.

Using two steps, you could first str.extract to get the digits and the rest of the text, then str.split and combine the two:
tmp = df['Header'].str.extract(r'((?:\d+ )+) *(.*)')

out = (tmp[0].str.split(expand=True)
       .rename(columns=lambda x: f'number{x+1}')
       .assign(Text=tmp[1])
      )

Output:
  number1 number2 number3                      Text
0       1    None    None   This is the first line.
1       2    None    None  This is the second line.
2       3       4    None   This is the third line.
3       5       6       7   This is a special line.


As there is already an answer with regex, I've given this answer without regex assuming the file's name is 'data.csv'. I see csv files separated with semicolons here. Then I came to know that the semicolons or comma varies according to the region. I've edited to comma now.
fl = open('data.csv', 'r')
ls = fl.readlines()
fl.close()

# list of index of first alphabet in each line
indices = []
for x in ls:
    for y in x:
        if y.isalpha():
            idx = x.index(y)
            indices.append(idx)
            break;

# maximum of the index of first alphabets in each line
txt_idx = max(indices)
new = []

for x in ls:
    for i,y in enumerate(x):
        if y.isalpha() and i < txt_idx:
            
            # multiplication factor = (txt_idx - i//2) + 1
            mf = int(((txt_idx -i)//2))
            
            # add mf times space and colen
            mid = '\t'*mf
            x = x[:i] + mid + x[i:]            
            new.append(x)
            break;
        elif y.isalpha() and i == txt_idx:
            new.append(x)
            break
    
with open('data.csv', 'w') as fl:
    fl.writelines(new)            

Text in old 'data.csv':
1,this is the first line
this is the second line
3,4,this is the third line
5,6,7,this is the fourth line



        

Text in New 'data.csv':
1,,,this is the first line
,,,this is the second line
3,4,,this is the third line
5,6,7,this is the fourth line


Don't pad the output with spaces. Use commas not semi-colons. The input data has no semi-colons, it just uses spaces. Don't overwrite the original file.

The comma / semicolon varies according to the region it seems. I've made it tab separated now.

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/change-excel-csv-delimiter/#:~:text=In%20North%20America%20and%20some,result%20is%20CSV%20semicolon%20delimited.

@MatBailie, I have removed the space as you suggested. Instead of semicolon. I've used \t now. So, let the op change it accordingly

@MatBailie, Thank you, Edited to comma now as I came to know that there is a separate file format tsv for tab separated.

The source data doesn't have commas either, it has spaces

@MatBailie, Source data shown by OP here is shown in table form. (i.e) to express how it will look like if the file is opened with excel or any spreadsheet application. But original delimiter of the csv files are either commas or semicolons. (csv files can be opened in excel or libreoffice calc. while opening there will be an initial dialogue box appear to change the setting). As I came to know that tab separated files (.tsv) have different extensions .tsv, I changed the delimiter to commas. You can verify.
